# How can I profile Apache Storm topologies without using the web dashboard?

Tags: performance, apache-storm

The title pretty much says it all, I have some Storm topologies and I'd like to measure their latencies, that is, the amount of time between a message coming in from Kafka and the last bit of related execution in the final bolt.  Bonus points if I can drill into the results to see the latency across each bolt.

Can this be done by simply tweaking the Storm configuration?

If not, is http://storm.incubator.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/hooks/info/SpoutAckInfo.html backtype.storm.hooks.info.SpoutAckInfo.completeLatencyMs the thing I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general profiling, we have a fork of storm where I enable the supervisor to dynamically set and open the JMX port equal to 1000 higher than the worker port (of course, this limits the number of workers we could assign, but we're nowhere near that problem now). Then with the supervisor.childopts value we assign the worker's JMX port and connect with Visual VM.

Specific to your metrics question, you can use the [BaseTaskHook](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/hooks/BaseTaskHook.java) to push the storm metrics to something with an MBean (we use codahale metrics) and again, browse the values over JMX. I posted an example [gist](https://gist.github.com/danehammer/b64c94b404680c485143). Note we haven't uplifted to 3.x of codahale metrics.

With Java 7 tools, I believe you're able to turn on JMX *on a running JVM*, so if you're on Java 7+, that would also help you.

Comment: That sounds good, but do you have more details on MetricsHook?  I don't see that name anywhere in the Storm docs...

Comment: My apologies, I incorrectly recalled how we accomplished this. Updated the answer and posted a gist.

Comment: So in your gist, you do a bunch of null checking on the lag values, do you know what a null value means in that context?  I tried it and almost all of the calls to that event have null latencies, but I'm at a loss for why.  Surely there's _some_ latency in the system...

Comment: Could this be related to the sampling? It defaults to 5%, so are you seeing a similar number of times you get null?

Comment: Ah yes, that's it.  Could someone upvote this answer and the above comment?  I don't have enough rep to up vote on this account :-(

Comment: Can we use VisualVM or jProfiler? How can I know which method is taking the most time?