# Apache Storm worker memory leak - outside heap

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, apache-storm

I have a 4 node storm cluster. 
Worker JVM parameters are as follows :

```
-Xms5g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m
```

Storm version : 0.9.3

Problem is : Worker tends to slow down significantly when process memory reaches to 14+GB.

My Top output is as follows at the time of snapping.

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                
 2075 root      20   0 18.132g 8.372g  12368 S  57.2 28.3  18:27.44 java
```

GC log :

```
3317.095: [GC pause (young), 0.1861930 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 180.9 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 3317095.5, Avg: 3317095.5, Max: 3317095.5, Diff: 0.0]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 29.0, Avg: 29.4, Max: 29.7, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 117.4]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 18.0, Avg: 18.1, Max: 18.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 72.5]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 31, Avg: 41.2, Max: 53, Diff: 22, Sum: 165]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.6, Avg: 0.7, Max: 0.8, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 2.8]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.4]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 132.1, Avg: 132.5, Max: 132.7, Diff: 0.6, Sum: 529.8]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.2]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 180.7, Avg: 180.8, Max: 180.8, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 723.1]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 3317276.3, Avg: 3317276.3, Max: 3317276.3, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.1 ms]
   [Code Root Migration: 0.2 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.4 ms]
   [Other: 4.6 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 1.4 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
      [Free CSet: 1.5 ms]
   [Eden: 2366.0M(2366.0M)->0.0B(1808.0M) Survivors: 94.0M->106.0M Heap: 5052.0M(15.0G)->2698.0M(15.0G)]
 [Times: user=0.73 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs]
```

I can see only 2698 MB of heap is used. But Linux Top is showing the RES memory as 8.372g. When the Top memory will reach to ~15GB the process will start clogging which I want to avoid.

Also, I have narrowed the possibility of Direct memory being clogged by some external API using the XX:MaxDirectMemorySize.

As the heap size is big - the worker crashes if I try to take a memory snapshot using a profiler(yourkit in my case).

I need to find the source where the memory is getting clogged.

Also, to avoid excess messages I have throttled the topology using TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING equal to 5.

I am using KafkaSpout - storm.kafka.KafkaSpout from /net/wurstmeister/storm/storm-kafka-0.8-plus/

Also i referred to this thread which has a similar issue but uses ZMQ instead of Netty which is used in newer versions of Storm.

[Spout memory leak](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/storm-user/spout$20memory$20leak/storm-user/WKdX_Enf2z4/BAjVOco1hoUJ)

UPDATE: When I remove all my bolts and only run the kafkaspout then there is minimal latency and also no memory issue. So, presumably we can suspect the processing bolt.

Comment: please add your spout code in post . are you using acking?.

Comment: Yes, mine is a reliable technology and I am using 4 Ackers with 4 Workers. @Gaurav : I am using KafkaSpout from wurstmeister. Do you want to see the server.properties configuration ?

Comment: It will better if you share spout code.

Comment: I have not written a custom spout - following is the github repo of the spout code: https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus

Comment: check your bolt must be you have some zombie Arraylist.

Comment: are you able to fix this.

Comment: Nope no luck till now. Gaurav, there is no arraylist where is created or maintained outside the execute() method. I believe execute() method's stack should get cleared after every call per tuple which is also indicated by the GC log. Not sure where should i see next to fix this.

Comment: See you have  anchored and acked  your code properly. share your code.

Comment: I am using BaseBasicBolt which has a default acking system.

Comment: its will good if you share your code.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, our discussion helped a lot. Actually shifting to CMS gc with a lot tuning parameters solved this.

Comment: @GauravMishra : This is one more issue in case this interests you!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314221/slow-topology-uneven-load-on-executers-in-a-storm-worker

Comment: "As the heap size is big - the worker crashes if I try to take a memory snapshot using a profiler(yourkit in my case)." -- A very helpful workaround for such cases (I know your pain) is to follow the instructions at [So you want your JVM’s heap…](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/so-you-want-your-jvms-heap/).  In short, you use gdb to perform a core dump of your Java process, then use jmap to convert the core dump into a standard hprof file (which can be read and analyzed by tools such as YourKit).

Comment: This is immensely helpful miguno, thanks a lot - would keep this in mind next time I sit to profile.

Comment: Linking a related question : [How can I profile Apache Storm topologies without using the web dashboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25042914/320399)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Actually the issue is that footprint of G1 is large for process memory but collection is more optimized.

While from the ParallelOldGC or CMS collector to G1, a larger JVM process size is largely related to "accounting" data structures such as Remembered Sets and Collection Sets.

Remembered Sets or RSets track object references into a given region. There is one RSet per region in the heap. The RSet enables the parallel and independent collection of a region. The overall footprint impact of RSets is less than 5%.

Collection Sets or CSets the set of regions that will be collected in a GC. All live data in a CSet is evacuated (copied/moved) during a GC. Sets of regions can be Eden, survivor, and/or old generation. CSets have a less than 1% impact on the size of the JVM.