# Slow topology - Uneven load on Executers in a Storm worker

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-storm

Structure to the problem :

```
4 node cluster
Bolt 2 - parallelism factor is 8, so 2 executers per worker.
```

I have notice lag overtime in the storm topology due to high latency in one of the executers.

[image]

If you'll notice in the pic, only 1 executer is having slightly more load and significantly high latency. Spout is working great!
Any pointer to the possible issues appreciated.

Noting unusual observer in worker/supervisor logs.

The worker JVM has high has huge memory so that is not a issue.

PS: cpu utilisation at the time of issue was >100% cumulative whereas on other nodes it was ~15%.
This is already narrowed that it is not a machine specific issue as this behaviour switches from one Executer to other in a cycle of few hours.

Comment: which Stream groupings are you using? check this executor is running on which node on nimbus node. try to shutdown that supervisor and see the pattern. your screen shot is not clearly visible.

Comment: My screenshot is saying : random executer(out of many) on a worker starts showing latency which I am unable to attribute to any issue. If I shutdown the supervisor then as per the timeout nimbus shifts the load to other ones which in time start showing similar behavior - > i believe this is not a node based issue but rather a configuration based issue. Might be some timeouts are happening but i don't see any failure in storm ui.

Comment: not sure.just look these parameters topology.executor.receive.buffer.size: xyz#batched
topology.executor.send.buffer.size: xyz#individual messages
topology.receiver.buffer.size: xyz # setting it too high causes a lot of problems (heartbeat thread gets starved, throughput plummets)
topology.transfer.buffer.size: xyz# batched on that node.

Comment: may be cross check no. of ackers

Comment: Yeah I have tried a few changes actually, these internal buffer parameters I have tried reading this blog http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/     ; but it does not affects my throughput.

Comment: Somehow, only few executers only have high latency - I am seriously unable to figure out what is causing this strange issue.

Comment: May be it is network issue between nodes.

Comment: Then actually all the bolts should show the same behaviour. why only the actual processing one. Because the same size messages actually travel through the nodes and same quantity too.

Comment: Hi Kaul, are you able to fix this.

Comment: Is it attached to a specific hardware / worker?

Comment: @GauravMishra : Right now i have disabled the acking to get some performance boost, works for me now but still have to find a permanent solution.     @ zenbeni : Nope almost 2/5 workers show this issue with one of the executers running on them. Not specific to machine.